# How to fetch web service response as a string in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, web-services, nsstring, response

I've webservice which converts CelsiusToFahrenheit. This webservice response is in string format instead of xml so how can I display a response in a label programmatically?
Is there a sample available for that?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest method is a one-liner:

```
NSError *error = nil;
myLabel.text = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:myURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
```

As with most one-line solutions, there's a caveat. This method blocks the current thread until the request completes or fails, so you'd better use it in conjunction with `performSelectorInBackground:withObject:` to avoid locking UI.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a tutorial that I used to retrieve data from a web service using the requestWithURL method of NSURLRequest:

http://mobileorchard.com/tutorial-json-over-http-on-the-iphone/

The example is for JSON, but you can just omit all of the JSON stuff from the tutorial, since the string response is going to be fed into your connectionDidFinishLoading method.